# Passport-twitter: failed to find request token in session

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

just yesterday on Heroku I started to have this error on twitter login in express

```
Error: failed to find request token in session
    at Strategy.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/passport-twitter/node_modules/passport-oauth/lib/passport-oauth/strategies/oauth.js:120:54)
    at Strategy.authenticate (/app/node_modules/passport-twitter/lib/passport-twitter/strategy.js:82:40)
    at Passport.authenticate (/app/node_modules/passport/lib/passport/middleware/authenticate.js:153:14)
    at callbacks (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:272:11)
    at param (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:246:11)
    at pass (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:253:5)
    at Router._dispatch (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:4)
    at Object.handle (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:45:10)
    at Context.next (/app/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/http.js:204:15)
    at Context.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/passport/lib/passport/context/http/actions.js:64:8)
```

any suggestion?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

YUHU I solved. the problem was that some times my website had www and sometimes not, so there were problems with sessions, apparently.

Comment: Here's [a gist of a route I used](https://gist.github.com/htsh/5796569) to remove leading www's from domain names after running into this same issue with passport

Answer (score 14):

I also encountered this error using Node.js, Express & Passport, although my fix was different than those described above.

I had copied and pasted the following code from the 'express-session' documentation...

```
app.use(session({ secret: 'keyboard cat', key: 'sid', cookie: { secure: true }}))
```

That **secure: true** bit instructs express-session to use 'https', which I don't have setup in my development environment.  Once I removed it, the error went away.

Comment: To keep it in production but otherwise remove it: `app.get('env') === 'production' ? true : false`

Comment: I didn't have `secure: true` but by forcing it to false it seemed to fix it for me.

Answer (score 7):

This is a very late answer, but I just figured another reason this can happen. 
When the guys who made **express-session** said that MemoryStore is not meant for production, they really meant it.

If you're using clustering, (pm2 or forever or running on Heroku), then memory based cookie storages have their own set of problems. You'll often loose cookies or corrupt them (because there are two or more separate processes on server side, not sharing common memory).

If you want to run your Node app with clusters, you need to use Redis or some DB-backed cookie storage

Answer (score 4):

In Twitters app settings, ensure the following fields have these values:

Website : http://127.0.0.1:3000

Callback URL : http://127.0.0.1:3000/auth/twitter/callback

**I am working with port number 3000.  You could change that to whatever port you are working with.

Now, navigate to http://127.0.0.1:3000 in your browser.  This should solve your problem.

Comment: I was getting this error because I was making the request to twitter from localhost:9000 and after the authentication, it was redirecting back to 127.0.0.1:9000 which is a different domain so the cookie will not be found as it was set on localhost and not 127.0.0.1. Replacing localhost with 127.0.0.1 worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is totally random, and I'm a Node newb... so apply salt liberally.

I was seeing this error and a very similar stack trace tonight, actually. It turned out that I had just changed my auth callback route to look like this:

`app.use('/auth/twitter/callback', twitterCallback);`

See how I used `use` there instead of `get`? Once I changed it back, I stopped getting this error.

My stack trace looked a bit different, though:

```
DEBUG: Error: failed to find request token in session
     at Strategy.<anonymous> (/Users/drhayes/src/incursion/node_modules/passport-twitter/node_modules/passport-oauth/lib/passport-oauth/strategies/oauth.js:122:54)  
     at Strategy.authenticate (/Users/drhayes/src/incursion/node_modules/passport-twitter/lib/passport-twitter/strategy.js:82:40)  
     at Passport.authenticate (/Users/drhayes/src/incursion/node_modules/passport/lib/passport/middleware/authenticate.js:153:14)  
     at Object.handle (native)  
     at next (/Users/drhayes/src/incursion/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/http.js:204:15)  
     at /Users/drhayes/src/incursion/node_modules/passport/lib/passport/middleware/authenticate.js:99:9  
     at /Users/drhayes/src/incursion/node_modules/passport/lib/passport/http/request.js:46:7  
     at pass (/Users/drhayes/src/incursion/node_modules/passport/lib/passport/index.js:229:30)  
     at /Users/drhayes/src/incursion/node_modules/passport/lib/passport/index.js:237:36  
     at /Users/drhayes/src/incursion/routes/auth.coffee:42:14
```

Has your source changed recently? Is there a revision bump in your deployed slug?

Comment: what do you mean for revision bump? Yes I change the code recently. I also found out that if I delete all sessions stored , I don't get the error.

Comment: Sorry, not revisions, but releases. Check out: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/releases Every time you push to Heroku, they increment the release number. You can use that to rollback on their side without using Git.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, it is due to reverse proxy and secure cookie. Setting `app.set('trust proxy', 1)` resolves the issue.

https://github.com/expressjs/session/issues/281#issuecomment-191327863

Comment: If anyone is using `ngrok` or `localtunnel` during development time, this will allow your backend service doing the auth to trust `1` hop from the UI callback to the auth, otherwise it will drop the session information.

Comment: Thanks. I actually ignored when `express-session` suggested that and forgot completely about that.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue, the solution was, take the site using http://127.0.0.1:3000/ instead http://localhost:3000, when the request happens everything works well.

Answer (score 1):

Twitter does not accept localhost so i was forced to use the following settings:

In https://apps.twitter.com/app/....

```
website = http://127.0.0.1:3000
callback url: http://localhost:3000/login/twitter/callback
```

In passport:

```
'callbackURL'       : 'http://localhost:3000/login/twitter/callback'
```

Note: The twitter callback url works using both 127.0.0.1 & localhost

Answer (score 1):

I used passport-flickr and fixed the same problem by changing **127.0.0.1** to **localhost**

```
passport.use(new FlickrStrategy({
    ...
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/flickr/callback"
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

`sameSite` seems to be another culprit. Going from

```
const SESSION_OPTIONS = {
  ...
  cookie: {
    sameSite: true,
  },
};
```

to

```
const SESSION_OPTIONS = {
  ...
  cookie: {
    sameSite: app.get('env') === 'production' ? true : false,
  },
};
```

did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this once, I fixed it by changing the call back URL

*from* **127.0.0.1**

*to* **localhost**

Comment: I have changed my cb url to localhost however twitter keeps returning to 127.0.0.1, maybe it takes time to propagate.

Answer (score 0):

Same symptom for me (no request token), but trying the other solutions here didn't help (`secure: false`, `localhost` vs `127.0.0.1`, etc.)

Turns out the problem was caused by an incorrect cookie configuration while using `cookie-session`. In my case, I was passing a number for the `expires` option, but that option expects a Date. Switched to using `maxAge` instead, which expects a number.